# Изменение значения data

Tags: html, css, jquery

Имею html doc:

```
<button class="divk" data-divs="0"></button>
```

css: {

```
.divk[data-divs="0"]::after {
    content: "HI";
}

.divk[data-divs="1"]::after {
    content: "BYE";
}
```

Хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки менялось содержимое кнопки. Пытался делать так:

> UPD

В чем разница:

```
$(this).parent().data("kav", "1");
```

и

```
var pres = document.querySelector(".btn");
pres.setdata.kav="1";
```

В первом случае меняется, во втором нет

Comment: Разница в том, что первое правильное, второе нет) `pres.dataset.kav = "1";` - должно работать.

Comment: почему-то не мeняет данное значение в атрибуте?пробовал через attr не помогает

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $('.divk').on('click', function () {
        $('.divk').attr('data-divs', "1");

    })
```

```css
   .divk[data-divs="0"]::after {
        content: "HI";
    }

    .divk[data-divs="1"]::after {
        content: "BYE";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="divk" data-divs="0"></button>
```

Comment: @Александр, работает, протестировал.

Comment: а как не через атрибуты реализовать, а через data?